# Add item to final list

Tags: java, android

i have a final List of Strings (it must be a final list inorder to use it in the SetonClickListener) and when i want to add item to this list it throws me an "UnSoppurtedOperationException"

this is the logcat:

```
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at com.example.sale.GroupActivity$MyCustomAdapter$1.onClick(GroupActivity.java:385)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-06 09:05:35.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1179):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 09:05:38.784: I/Process(1179): Sending signal. PID: 1179 SIG: 9
04-06 09:05:39.694: E/Trace(1425): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

and this is my code:

```
          String name="a";

          String freindsAccepted = groupFreindsAcceptedInside.get(position);

            final List<String> accepted = Arrays.asList(freindsAccepted.split(","));
            final String[] arrayAccepted = accepted.toArray(new String[accepted.size()]);

acceptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  Thread thread = new Thread()
                  {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {

                          //perform something
                      }
                  };

                  thread.start();

                  accepted.add(name);
                  String[] arrayAcceptedInside = accepted.toArray(new String[accepted.size()]);

                    if(accepted.size()>1) {
                        groupAccepted.setText("Accepted: "+accepted.get(0)+","+ accepted.get(1)+"...see More");
                    }
                    else {
                        groupAccepted.setText("Accepted: "+accepted.get(0));

                    }
              }
          });
```

where line 385 is:

```
          accepted.add(name);
```

thanks alot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem isn't that it's a final variable - the problem is that the object is the return value of `Arrays.asList`:

```
final List<String> accepted = Arrays.asList(freindsAccepted.split(","));
```

From the documentation of [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

It sounds like you possibly want to create a new `ArrayList` (which will allow adding):

```
final List<String> accepted = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList(freindsAccepted.split(","));
```

(It's not clear why you've got the `arrayAccepted` and `arrayAcceptedInside` variables, by the way - were they just for diagnostics?)

Comment: thanks, so how can i add items to this list? without throw an exception?

Comment: hi Jon, i have two array only for the debugging, thanks alot, your answer helped me alot :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not because the variable is final that is fine, its becase Arrays.asList returns a fixed sized list:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29

you can wrap this in a new ArrayList to solve the problem:

```
    final List<String> accepted = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(freindsAccepted.split(",")));
```